# Can $\sigma(2^r)$ be abundant for $r > 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the *sum of the divisors* of the positive integer $x$.  If $\sigma(y) < 2y$, $y$ is called *deficient*; if $\sigma(z) > 2z$, $z$ is called *abundant*.

**Questions**

> > **(1)** Can $\sigma(2^r)$ be abundant for some integer $r > 1$?
> >
> > **(2)** If so, what conditions on $r$ guarantee abundance?

**My Attempt**

If $\sigma(2^r) = 2^{r + 1} - 1$ is a *Mersenne prime*, then it is deficient.  Hence we consider the case when $\sigma(2^r) = 2^{r + 1} - 1$ is a *composite Mersenne number*.

I found this related question in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110364).  It essentially states the following proposition:

> **Proposition A.** If $n = {2^{m-1}}(2^m - 1)$, where $m$ is a positive integer such that $2^m - 1$ is composite, then $n$ is abundant.

Suppose to the contrary that $\sigma(2^r) = 2^{r+1} - 1$ is a **deficient** composite Mersenne number.  Since $2^{r - 1}$ is also deficient, then *subject to certain constraints on the abundancy index*
$$I\left(\sigma(2^r)\right)=\dfrac{\sigma\left(\sigma(2^r)\right)}{\sigma(2^r)},$$
(such as a suitable upper bound), then it might be possible to show that
$$I(k) = I\left({2^{r-1}}\sigma(2^r)\right) < 2,$$
contradicting **Proposition A**.

**"QED"**

**In Retrospect**

However, I do realize that this argument is not rigorous, and may in fact be fallacious.  This explains my second question.

Comment: What about $r = 11$? $\sigma(2^{11}) = 2^{12}-1 = 4095 = 3^2\cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 13$, and $\sigma(\sigma(2^{11})) = \sigma(3^2)\sigma(5)\sigma(7)\sigma(13) = 13\cdot 6\cdot 8 \cdot 14 = 8736 > 2\cdot 4095$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, yes that is correct.  I guess my main question would be: What condition(s) characterize(s) such integers $r$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since integer $r > 1$ implies that $r - 1 \geq 1$, and since
$$2 \mid 2^{r - 1}$$
and
$$\gcd(2^{r - 1}, \sigma(2^r)) = 1,$$
then a condition on $r$ that guarantees abundance (by ensuring a contradiction against **Proposition A**) follows from the fact that the *abundancy index* is **weakly multiplicative**:
$$\dfrac{3}{2} \cdot I\left(\sigma(2^r)\right) \leq I(2^{r-1})I\left(\sigma(2^r)\right) = I\left(2^{r-1}\sigma(2^r)\right) = I(k) < 2$$
so that
$$I\left(\sigma(2^r)\right) < \dfrac{4}{3}.$$
This condition on $r$ will ensure a deficient $k = {2^{r-1}}\sigma(2^r)$ thereby contradicting **Proposition A**.

Consequently, the condition
$$I\left(\sigma(2^r)\right) > \dfrac{4}{3}$$
is necessary for $\sigma(2^r)$ to be abundant. (Note that
$$I\left(\sigma(2^r)\right) \neq \dfrac{4}{3}$$
since it is assumed that $r \neq 1$.)

**Added June 2 2016**

> Is the condition
>   $$I\left(\sigma(2^r)\right) > \dfrac{4}{3}$$
>   also sufficient for $\sigma(2^r)$ to be abundant?